# Subtracting the result of two sums

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to subtract two totals.
I have one table for incomes, were the final row is the "total incomes" and another table for expenses, with a final row for the "total expenses"
I need to add another function that calculates the total income minus the total expenses. I also need to show a negative amount in case the expenses are greater than the incomes.

My problem is, I don't quite understand how to use the value that its stored on my previous function so I can reuse it on the new one. I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery so I'm having troubles understanding the documentation.
Any guidance on this will be very much appreciated

Here is the js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txtA").each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            calculateSumA();
            calculateSubstraction();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSumA() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txtA").each(function () {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sumA").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function () {

        $(this).keyup(function () {
            calculateSum();
            calculateSubstraction();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function () {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}


function calculateSubstraction() {
    var subs = calculateSum() - calculateSumA();
    $("#subs").html(subs.toFixed(2));

}
```

here is the html

```
<body>
<table width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>income</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>income</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>income</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>income</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>income</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>income</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="income">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">total income:</td>
        <td align="center"><span id="sumA">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>expense</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>expense</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>expense</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>expense</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>expense</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>expense</td>
        <td>
            <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right">total expenses:</td>
        <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table width="300px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40px"></td>
        <td style="width:62px">Remaining:</td>
        <td align="center"><span id="su">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gnzLwzuy/5/
I know it could be optimized, as I'm repeating the code too much, but If I change it too much It stops working.
(I have too much to learn...)

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement Guruprasad answer, and to responde directly to **how can a function access a value calculated by another function**.

**The easy way**:

1 - declare global variables and use them inside your functions.

```
var foo;

function calculateSumA() {
  ....
  foo = some value;
}

function OtherFunc() {
  ....
  var localVar = foo;
}
```

2 - make the functions return a value and store it somewhere other functions can access (e.g a global variable);

**Not so simple way**:

You can use closures to create the illusion of private members.
I wrote an article on JS Closures. I believe it will help you understand the concept quite well, if you are curious about it: https://usonsci.wordpress.com/2014/10/04/closure-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

However you are calling `calculateSubstraction` on `keyup` of each `textbox` just take the value from `total` of each `section` and `subtract` it accordingly as below:

```
function calculateSubstraction() {
    var subs=parseFloat($("#sumA").text()) - parseFloat($("#sum").text())
    $("#su").html(subs);

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gnzLwzuy/8/)**

---

**Update**

Here is the more optimized version of your `code`. I prefer `blur` event than `keyup` since its more reliable to calculate and reduces the firing of event on every `keypress`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var income = 0;//variable to hold income
    var expense= 0; //variable to hold expense
    $(".txtA,.txt").blur(function () { //attach event to multiple elements
        $(this).each(function () {//loop through each of them
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                if($(this).hasClass('txt')) //if it is expense
                    expense += parseFloat(this.value); //add it to expense
                else
                    income+=parseFloat(this.value); //add it to income
            }
        });
        if($(this).hasClass('txt'))
            $("#sum").html(expense.toFixed(2)); //display based on income or expense
        else
            $("#sumA").html(income.toFixed(2));
        calculateSubstraction();//this remains same

    });
});
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gnzLwzuy/12/)**

Comment: I appreciate the help to optimize my code, however the code you provided does not sums properly. If you delete or overwrite the value of an input, the total does not updates properly.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gnzLwzuy/11/)

You need to return a value from the add functions so add

```
return sum.toFixed(2);
return sum.toFixed(2);
```

from the two function and did the subtraction from the subtract function

```
var data = calculateSum();
var dataa = calculateSumA();
var subs = dataa-data;
$("#su").html(subs.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: you are calling the `calculateSum()` and `calculateSumA()` twice..I think it's redundant

Comment: @DyrandzFamador are you pointing at the keyup?i didnt actually do it i just edited that from question

Answer (score 0):

I've made a pure Javascript version of your code, and added two new functionalities:

- A button to dynamically add new rows to the `income` and `expense` tables.
- And remove the ability of user adding anything other than numbers to the textfields.

The full commented code is below:

```js
/* when all elements of the page are available */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* get the tables income and expense, and the 'total' fields */
  var income = document.getElementById('income'),
      expense = document.getElementById('expense'),
      totalIncome = document.getElementById('totalIncome'),
      totalExpense = document.getElementById('totalExpense'),
      total = document.getElementById('total');

  /* create the calculate function */
  function calculate(e) {
    /* get all the textfields of each table */
    var incomes = [].slice.call(income.querySelectorAll('input')),
        expenses = [].slice.call(expense.querySelectorAll('input'));

    /* calculate the sum of the fields by using
       - map to convert the values to numbers
       - and reduce to sum those values */
    var sumIncome = incomes.map(function(el) {
      /* don't allow users to input other values than numbers */
      el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
      return Number(el.value);
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });

    var sumExpense = expenses.map(function(el) {
      /* don't allow users to input other values than numbers */
      el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
      return Number(el.value);
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
    
    /* change the totalIncome and totalExpense labels */
    totalIncome.textContent = sumIncome;
    totalExpense.textContent = sumExpense;

    /* change the total remaining label */
    total.textContent = sumIncome - sumExpense;
  }
  
  /* add the event handlers to the oninput event to both tables
     they will call the calculate function above when they happen */
  income.addEventListener('input', calculate);
  expense.addEventListener('input', calculate);

  /* this is a bonus, I've added 'new' buttons to dynamically add more rows */
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var el = e.target;

    if (el.className === 'new') {
      var table = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode,
        tr = document.createElement('tr');

      tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + [].slice.call(table.querySelectorAll('tr')).length + '</td>\
                      <td>income</td>\
                      <td>\
                        <input class="txtA" type="text" />\
                      </td>';
      table.insertBefore(tr, el.parentNode.parentNode);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
.txt,
.txtA {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id='income' width="300px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="income">
    <td>
      <button class="new">new</button>
    </td>
    <td align="right">total income:</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="totalIncome">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table id='expense' width="300px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="new">new</button>
    </td>
    <td align="right">total expenses:</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="totalExpense">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table width="300px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:40px"></td>
    <td style="width:62px">Remaining:</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="total">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like the idea of preventing the user from entering anything that's not a number, however that prevents them also from entering decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your calculateSubstraction() function with this :

```js
function calculateSubstraction() {
var Income =  parseFloat($('#sumA').html());
var Expense =  parseFloat($('#sum').html());
var subs = Income - Expense;
$("#su").html(subs.toFixed(2));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can have a simple calculation like

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var sum = {
    income: 0,
    deduction: 0
  };
  $('input.entry').keyup(function() {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table'),
      total = 0;
    $table.find('input.entry').each(function() {
      total += +this.value || 0;
    });
    $table.find('span.total').html(total)
    sum[$table.data('type')] = total;
    $('#su').html(sum.income - sum.deduction);
  })
})
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: sans-serif;
 }
 table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-color: white;
   background-color: powderblue;
 }
 input.entry {
   background-color: #FEFFB0;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300px" border="1" class="entry" data-type="income">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>income</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txtA entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="income">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">total income:</td>
    <td align="center"><span class="total">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table width="300px" border="1" class="entry" data-type="deduction">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>expense</td>
    <td>
      <input class="txt entry" type="text" name="txt" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">total expenses:</td>
    <td align="center"><span class="total">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table width="300px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:40px"></td>
    <td style="width:62px">Remaining:</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="su">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, your code its really short compared to what I had. Would you mind explaining the ".closest" part?

Comment: @JaneBell .closest() will give the closest ancestor element matching the selector... in this case it will return the table which contains the changed input

Comment: so that's why the same function can be recycled for both tables, right? Say, if I´d like to create a 3rd table with the same functionality (adding value of input to get a total) it will also work on that one.
Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JaneBell yes... it will